# What are the advantages and disadvantages of connecting Puppeteer over pipe instead of a websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

Puppeteer supports connection to the browser either using a websocket (default) or using a pipe.

```
puppeteer.launch({ pipe: true });
```

What are the advantages of either of those approaches? Why would I choose one over the other? What are their disadvantages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pipes` should be your default if you run everything (puppeteer and chromium) in the same server. They are even [considering](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2079) making that the default. The pro is that's a private connection between puppeteer and chromium. You are not opening a WebSocket to "the world". The con is that you can't re-use the chromium instance with another puppeteer process.

I think you can infer the pros and cons of `WebSockets` from the previous paragraphs. You would use `WebSocket` if you need to share a chromium instance across many puppeteer processes or from a different computer.

There are no big differences in performance though.

Comment: I'd add that when using websocket on a PC, and the PC goes to sleep, the connection is lost when the PC wakes up. With a pipe the session just continues as you'd expect